# NSMutableArray initWithObjects Not Working

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

Ey guys, I am having some problems adding NSURLs to an array and looping through them. Here are the relevant portions of my code:

RSS_ReaderAppDelegate.h:

```
@interface RSS_ReaderAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

    UIWindow *window;
    UINavigationController *navigationController;

    NSDictionary *RSSFeeds;
    NSMutableArray *RSSFeedURLs;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *RSSFeeds;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *RSSFeedURLs;
```

RSS_ReaderAppDelegate.m:

```
@implementation RSS_ReaderAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize navigationController;

@synthesize RSSFeeds, RSSFeedURLs;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    NSURL *url1 = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://<some url>"]; //real URL has been hidden
    NSURL *url2 = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://<some other url>"]; //real URL has been hidden

    [RSSFeedURLs initWithObjects: url1, url2, nil];

    [url1 release];
    [url2 release];

    for (NSURL *url in RSSFeedURLs) { //jumps right over this for loop
        NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
        XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] init];
        [xmlParser setDelegate:parser];
        //Start parsing the XML file.
        BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];

        if(success)
            NSLog(@"No Errors");
        else
            NSLog(@"Error(s) encountered");
    }//for
    // Add the navigation controller's view to the window and display.
    [window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

So `[RSSFeedURLs initWithObjects: url1, url2, nil];` doesn't seem to actually do anything as when I run the debugger and type "po RSSFeedsURLs" it reports: "Cannot access memory at address 0x0", and thus the for loop is never entered. I have no idea why this is so, can anyone shed some light on this situation for me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want:

```
RSSFeedURLs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: url1, url2, nil];
```

but you should want:

```
rssFeedURLs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: url1, url2, nil];
```

Variables starting with capital letters lead to much confusion.

Comment: Foolish me! Can't believe I didn't see that! And yes, you are right about the variable naming convention, thanks for pointing that out as well. :)

Comment: As per Apple's code naming guidelines for Cocoa, "For method names, start with a lowercase letter and capitalize the first letter of embedded words. Don’t use prefixes. **An exception to this guideline is method names that start with a well-known acronym, for example, TIFFRepresentation (NSImage)**. Either that, or spell it out: richSiteSummaryFeedURL or  ratherSimpleSyndicationFeedURL, but I guess that RSS is well-know enough to use it as is.